# How do I configure S3ForcePathStyle with AWS golang v2 SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

I'm putting and reading files to S3 using the [AWS golang v2 SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2). Locally I am using local stack and thus need to set the param `S3ForcePathStyle`. But, I can't find where to set this parameter in the config.

This is what my config looks like:

```golang
conf, err = config.LoadDefaultConfig(
            context.TODO(),
            config.WithRegion("us-east-1"),
            config.WithEndpointResolver(
                aws.EndpointResolverFunc(func(service, region string) (aws.Endpoint, error) {
                    return aws.Endpoint{
                        PartitionID:   "aws",
                        URL:           "http://localstack:4566",
                        SigningRegion: "us-east-1",
                    }, nil
                }),
            ),
        )
```

Where can I pass in `S3ForcePathStyle = true`?

Comment: What about [Config.WithS3ForcePathStyle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/#Config.WithS3ForcePathStyle)?

Comment: @amitd OP was requesting for V2. `Config.WithS3ForcePathStyle`  is for AWS SDK V1 only

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Seems I was looking in the wrong place. The documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-sdk-for-go-version-2-general-availability/) explains that in aws-sdk-go-v2 they moved the service-specific configuration flags to the individual service client option types. Ironically to improve discoverability.

I should set the `UsePathStyle` like this:

```golang
client := s3.NewFromConfig(conf, func(o *s3.Options) {
    o.UsePathStyle = true
})
```

Comment: For those who are looking the same for JavaScript (node.js) it is: `const s3 = new S3({forcePathStyle: true});`